# Using Perfect Infinitive

Tags: infinitives

I can say:

> I saw her leave.

Although the first variant is clear, I wonder to know if I can use Perfect Infinitive in the following statement:

> I heard him to have moved to London.

Maybe, it would be better to say:

> I heard that he had moved to London.

Comment: Yes, the second one is much better.

Comment: **know|believe him to have** + {past participle} is rather moribund as constructions go.  Not that you won't find it.  But it never uses **hear** or **heard**.